# Spring @Transactional behaviour with only one transactional data source

Tags: java, mysql, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I have an app that accesses two databases. Obviously, if I need to have a transaction span both DBs, I need to use something like two phase commit. But I don't need this king of guarantee right now, I don't need everything to be transactional. Things can crash or succeed independently, the app can handle it and not end-up in an inconsistent state.

Right now I have a setup like this one (removed interfaces, code, etc to make it as simple as possible to explain):

Two data sources:

```
<bean id="firstDS" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <qualifier value="firstDS" />
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/firstDS" />
</bean>

<bean id="secondDS" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <qualifier value="secondDS" />
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/secondDS" />
</bean>
```

One transaction manager for **only one** of the data sources:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="firstDS" />
</bean>
```

A service:

```
@Service
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    private FirstDao firstDao;

    @Autowired
    private SecondDao secondDao;

    public void updateStuff() {
        firstDao.updateStuff();
        secondDao.updateStuff();
    }
}
```

and two DAOs:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public class FirstDao {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("firstDS")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void updateStuff() {
        // updates stuff in the first database using dataSource
    }
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public class SecondDao {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("secondDS")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void updateStuff() {
        // updates stuff in the second database using dataSource
    }
}
```

Now, this runs without problems (or at least none that I could observe) but my questions are:

- is this safe or does it have any side effects?
- How does the second DAO behave since it is transactional but the transaction is for another database?
- Should I remove the @Transactional annotation from the second DAO? Will it then behave just like any other method call?

I've read the reference and various posts online but I still am not sure about the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it safe ?

No. `SecondDao.updateStuff` will be executed without logical transaction. It means that every single query executed during `SecondDao.updateStuff` will be executed in a separate *physical transaction* in auto-commit mode. In other words : `SecondDao.updateStuff` is not transactional (and may even use one separate connection for every query... which can lead to performance problems).

What can you do ?

First declare a transactionManager for your secondDS :

```
<tx:annotation-driven/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="firstDS" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager2" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="secondDS" />
</bean>
```

Then specify that SecondDAO use transactionManger2 :

```
@Transactional(value="transactionManager2",propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class SecondDao {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("secondDS")
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void updateStuff() {
        // updates stuff in the second database using dataSource
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ben75. Could you elaborate a bit on your response. For example, why would the second DAO use one separate connection for every query? It has its own data source configured so it will take a connection from there. Both data sources are pooled, I didn't mention that, does it still cause performance problems? Also, how does the second transaction manager help fix it. I'm just trying to understand the fix you proposed. Thanks again!

Comment: I didn't say that it will always take a new connection, it depends on your setup. The fact that you are using a connection pool isn't relevant for this potential problem. It is related to the connection release mode.

Comment: Defining a transationManger2 for secondDS will simply inform spring that every access to secondDS must also be inside *logical transaction* delimited with @Transactional annotations. Please note the important attribute value="transactionManager2" for transactional method secondDS.  You must also know that the default value for the value attribute is "transactionManager".

Comment: *It is related to the connection release mode*. In what way? Connections are not released? Leaks you mean?